# La dependencia de thymeleaf en springboot no funciona

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf, dependencias

estoy empezando con un proyecto en springboot, y tengo un error que nunca habia visto y no he podido solucionarlo, es con la dependencia de thymeleaf no funciona, estoy trabajando con intellij idea community edition . no me deja usar el texto th:, vea la imagen. Eliminé el proyecto y lo volví a descargar varias veces, eliminé la carpeta m2 y nada me funciona. Me he dado cuenta que ninguna de las otras dependencias funcionan pero no entiendo el motivo.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@GetMapping(value = "/index")
public String index(Model model){
model.addAttribute("titulo", "nombre");
return "index";
}
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>th:text="${titulo}"</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

cuando ejecuto el código localhost no me muestra la información correcta, ya tengo instalada la dependencia.

[image: imagen del localhost]

mi archivo pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
   https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.springboot.web.app</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>spring-boot-demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

tampoco me funciona devtools

Comment: El th va en la etiqueta de apertura: <title th:text="${titulo}"></title>. Lo estas poniendo de manera incorrecta.

Comment: Gracias sabes como hacer para que actualice el localhost sin tener que cerrar y lanzar el servidor

Comment: Si colocas en tu `application.properties` la línea  `spring.thymeleaf.cache=false` y 
`spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:src/main/resources/templates/` debería tomarte los cambios en thymeleaf sin tener que reiniciar el servidor, solo debes darle `reload` en tu navegador. Checa más detalles en [este](https://lifesaver.codes/answer/how-to-reload-templates-without-restarting-the-spring-boot-application-614) enlace.

Comment: Aunque si tienes `spring-boot-devtools` en tu `pom` deberías poder visualizar los cambios sin tener que reiniciar.

Comment: Si ahí lo tengo pero no me esta funcionando

Comment: Agrega lo que te comenté al `application.properties`.

Comment: Ahora si me funciona pero deberia funcionar el devtools, no ? sabes como arreglarlo

Comment: Ahora que leo bien tu pregunta usas `IntelliJ`. En `IntelliJ` no basta solamente con agregar la dependencia, debes ir a *File > Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler* y seleccionar *Build project automatically*. Luego en la misma ventana de configuración selecciona en el menú izquierdo al final `Advanced Settings` y selecciona `Allow auto-make to start`. Eso debería solucionar el problema. No olvides presionar `Apply`.

Comment: Oye ya me funciono muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El problema reside en que escribiste la sintaxis de thymeleaf fuera de la etiqueta title

```
<title>th:text="${titulo}"</title>
```

intenta escribiendola de la siguiente forma:

```
<title th:text="${titulo}"></title>
```

Saludos!